# UNIX: Send Mail using SMTP Server

Tags: unix, smtp, email

I would like to send an email through a remote SMTP server. How can this be done? I will be sending the email from a bash shell script.

I'm using a unix machine. `uname -a` returns:

```
Linux linux 2.4.21 BrandZ fake linux i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Contacting a remote SMTP server directly is not generally the way this is done. What, for example, if the server is temporarily unavailable?

The easier route is to run a local mailserver such as postfix, exim or qmail, and set it up to send mail through a remote server. Then you can just use command-line `sendmail` to send your e-mail.

In postfix on Ubuntu, I put the following in master.cf:

```
relayhost = [smtp.my-isp.com]
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

You need the last line in case your ISP's mail server requires that all outgoing mail originates from `you@your-isp.com`. Then you'll also need /etc/postfix/generic like this:

```
youruser@localhost you@your-isp.com
```

Add other variants (e.g. `youruser@yourbox.yourdomain`) as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `mailx` command can be used to send email non-interactively,
but the classical implementation talks to a local mail transport agent.
There are simple MTAs which will just send email through a remote SMTP server,
and won't accept any local email.

Another solution is to use [`heirloom-mailx`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html),
(formerly known as `nail` I think)
which supports talking to an SMTP server directly instead of using a local MTA.
For instance, you may invoke it as follows:

```
heirloom-mailx -S smtp=smtp.your-isp.com \
               -S from=you@your-isp.com \
               -s "subject" <<EOM
Hello, $name,
This is an automatic reminder, sent out once a month, ...
[the rest of your message]
EOM
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if it still works.. but you might wanne use telnet. at least you should be able to write a bashscript using it